# Letting users subscribe to messages that have certain tags in a Google Groups

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-tags

I have a Google group, and the discussion is slowly catching up. We use several tags for each post.

Is there a way to let users subscribe ONLY to some tags?

Either directly through the Google Groups setting, or by letting the email arrive with the tag listed, and then setting up a filter system on the mail program that only keeps unread messages with certain keywords.

I could not find ways to subscribe to a single tag, nor ways to add the tags in an email (to filter later).